# StarCraft II profile URL path

Tags: starcraft-2

I want to make a SC2 clan and we need an website. We want to let users register free on website based on Server, Character Name and Number.

I saw on http://sc2ranks.com/ that they can somehow can find / construct player profile URL, for example: http://sc2ranks.com/cn/85055/ZeroKyo

From where did they get `/85055/`? It isn't based on anything as far I can see. How can I find this URL if I have the character name and number?

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use the API that sc2ranks.com has created. That way you can focus your efforts on building the website, and sc2ranks will deliver the data you need.

Read more about the restrictions for the service and how to use [SC2 Ranks API](http://sc2ranks.com/api).

EDIT

Since you do not want to use sc2ranks.com, you should take a look at [the sc2profile project](https://bitbucket.org/henry/sc2profile/overview). It is made for the single purpose of fetching profile information from Battle.net. I think that would be a good starting point.

Comment: +1 This seems like it would be the easiest and quickest method to implement. If nothing else the OP should at least use this until they can come up with their own platform (if they wish to do so)

Comment: The only problem with this is your relying on a third party website. Should it go down, you would have to rewrite everything.

Comment: @Resorath But it's a good method to use until they have their own system in place.

Answer (score 1):

That number is from the user's battle.net profile URL. Example:

[http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/**326029**/1/LiquidTLO/](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/326029/1/LiquidTLO/)

[http://sc2ranks.com/eu/**326029**/LiquidTLO](http://sc2ranks.com/eu/326029/LiquidTLO)

That's probably how sc2ranks gets it, but if all you have is username + character code, I don't know a way to get it without using their API like @Sharken said. However even on their website they say character code is not the most accurate way to search for a player's profile.